# Wake up react native app with a fcm notification

Tags: firebase, react-native

Wake up react native app to obtain fcm token push notification firebase
Wake up device (turn on screen) when notifications arrived on Android Current Situation
When notifications arrived, sounds and vibrations are working, but screen is off.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?